# Repeat a clip down entire timeline

Tags: premiere, cc-2014

Is there a better way to take a short video loop (in my case a video watermark) and duplicate it again and again down the full length of my sequence than my current workflow?

## Current Workflow

1. Place the clip in the sequence
2. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> down and drag a copy down the timeline
3. Select the new copy and snap it back against the first one
4. Select both clips
5. Holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, drag a new copy of them down the line
6. Select all clips and repeat step 5.
7. Repeat 5 & 6 until the clip is looped down the full length of the sequence.

Any insight into a faster solution would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fast way to copy the clips in succession.

1. Copy the video clip <kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>
2. Target ONLY the track that the loop will be on
3. Then swiftly insert it multiple times by just holding down <kbd>CMD</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd> and pressing <kbd>V</kbd> multiple times in a row

Comment: I should have thought of that! It's MUCH faster than what I've been doing. Thanks a million, I edited the question a little to make it clearer.

Comment: Accepted, it certainly is clearer that way ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Building on the cut/paste workflow. You could create the clip in AfterEffects and make it very long. Then just dynamic link to your project.

This way at least -every time you need to use it- you don't have to copy/paste over again. Just drop the one clip and size to need. Also can be useful if you need a varying opacity through the clip, since you don't have to adjust a bunch of clips separately.

Comment: Not a bad idea, except that for my situation, I'm doing a different clip most of the time, so it would actually take longer.